# Access 2010 - Choose a file and import a Excel work sheet to a table Macro or VB

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, import-from-excel

I am trying to make a form where the users of the DB can push a button "add new customers" which will open a file browser where the user selects a Excel file with the same rows as the table `Customers`.

When the user has selected the Excel file, the rows are added to the `Customers` table. Lets say the table `Customers` contains:

ID(auto) 
First name 
Last Name 
phone number

Any good examples?

I have a good understanding of DB's but not so much VBA, but I can interpret what I read.

Thanks in advance!